# In KDB, is their a straightforward way of doing `more` for lists and tables?

Tags: kdb

I frequently have to explore the actual data by looking through it.

The problem I encounter is:

```
til 100
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 ..
q)
```

Everything gets truncated in the REPL.

Is there an easy way to explore data in KDB? (I'm using the REPL in combination with `vim-cmdline`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box KDB+ doesn't offer this ability.

If you want to display more data on the screen can expand your console size (up to a certain limit) via the `\c` system command or `-c` command line parameter
https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#c-console-size

You could also use in-built functions like `_` (drop), `sublist`, or `?` (find) to locate and display particular data of interest.

```
q)l:til 100
q)(-5+l?40;11) sublist l  // Show 5 records either side of 40
```

There are also some IDEs for KDB+ that might help:
http://www.qinsightpad.com/
https://github.com/CharlesSkelton/studio
https://code.kx.com/developer/

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Seans suggestion, you can also use `cut` to see more of a list:

```
q)20 cut til 100
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

It can be useful sometimes but it's situational.

Same goes for using `#` to reshape:

```
0N 20#til 100

20 0N#til 100
```